# jquery send get and change image source

Tags: javascript, jquery

by clicking on the image i want send data to /log.php?image_id=$id

$image_id =  id from this html

```
<img src="./image/001/001.jpg" id="v1">
<img src="./image/001/002.jpg" id="v2">
<img src="./image/001/003.jpg" id="v3">
<img src="./image/001/004.jpg" id="v4">
```

after click change image source on off.jpg

How this possible on JQuery ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('img').click(function()
    {
        var self = this;
        $.post('/log.php', {image_id: $(self).attr('id')}, function(e)
        {
            $(self).attr('src', 'off.jpg');
        });
    });
});
```